# I added a custom_target related to node-gyp, but reported the error that VS cannot be found

Tags: node.js, cmake

It's my project structure:

```
/
 CMakelists.txt
 ...
 /node
      binding.gyp
      ...
```

in CMakelists.txt:

```
option(NEED_COMPILE_NODE_BINDING ON)

if(NEED_COMPILE_NODE_BINDING)
add_custom_target(node_binding ALL 
  COMMAND node-gyp rebuild
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/node
  )
endif()
```

It's report:

```
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS 
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS - not found
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS 
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
[build]   gyp ERR! find VS 
[build]   gyp ERR! configure error
```

But if I enter the `node` directory and use the command directly in powershell, it will not report an error.

Do i need to set something?

thx.